# Ignite not launching with example configuration, "Cannot find class CassandraHelper for bean"

Tags: spring, maven, cassandra, javabeans, ignite

I'm attempting to put Cassandra into Ignite for some prototyping, and I'm encountering some difficulties getting Ignite to launch.

So far all I've done to Ignite is alter the default-config.xml, add a connection-settings.xml and add dependencies for Cassandra/Ignite to the libs folder.

At this point, I am unable to launch Ignite. All errors appear to be related to classes referenced in connection-settings.xml.

My debugging:
I started with the error

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraHelper] for bean with name 'contactPoints' defined...
```

I downloaded Ignite's source code to check that the files where where the paths in connection-settings.xml said they were, and that they contain the expected function(s).

find . -name CassandraHelper.java told me there are two such files with that name in Ignite's source:

```
./modules/cassandra/store/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/cassandra/common/CassandraHelper.java
./modules/cassandra/store/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/tests/utils/CassandraHelper.java
```

Only the latter of those two actually contains the function getContactPointsArray. Out of curiousity, I changed connection-settings.xml to point to org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.common.CassandraHelper, and sure enough, the error changed from "Cannot find class" to "No such method 'getContactPointsArray'".

Looking at the source code I found that the other files Ignite was failing to find were also at their expected location under the src/test directory rather than src/main, so I suspect that -for some reason- Ignite is searching under src/main when it should be searching under src/test. This doesn't seem like something I should have to configure manually, and I'm not sure how I would tell Ignite via connection-settings.xml to look under the other directory.

I am anything but an expert when it comes to Ignite and Cassandra, so I would not be surprised if I've made some weird mistake in setting things up, but so far I can't figure out what mistake I may have made. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My files:

default-config.xml (taken from https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.6/docs/examples, I removed cache2).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Cassandra connection settings -->
    <import resource="connection-settings.xml" />

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache1' -->
    <bean id="cache1_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/persistence/blob/persistence-settings-1.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Ignite configuration -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache1" cache -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                    <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource"/>
                    <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
                </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

connection-settings.xml (taken from the same webpage, AdminCredentials stuff removed as several other StackOverflow threads mention they aren't needed at small prototype phase)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>

    <bean id="contactPoints" class="org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraHelper" factory-method="getContactPointsArray"/>

    <bean id="cassandraAdminDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.datasource.DataSource">
        <property name="credentials" ref="cassandraAdminCredentials"/>
        <property name="contactPoints" ref="contactPoints"/>
        <property name="readConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>
    </bean>
        <bean id="cassandraRegularDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource">
        <property name="credentials" ref="cassandraRegularCredentials"/>
        <property name="contactPoints" ref="contactPoints"/>
        <property name="readConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml for dependancies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ignite -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cassandra -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ignite-Cassandra Bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-cassandra-store</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-cassandra-serializers</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>    

    <!-- Discontinued? 1.8.0 is latest. 
          I think ignite-cassandra-store replaced this. -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency> -->



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <mainClass>com.myapp.myclass</mainClass>
                          </transformer>
                      </transformers>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Used to package all our dependancies. Ignite needs this. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By Mitya's suggestion and some trial and error, I've altered cassandraRegularDataSource to use `<property name="contactPoints" value="localhost"/>` rather than defining a bean. This solved that issue, however I'm still debugging some other aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraHelper` class is used for Ignite tests only, and obviously it's not included in release package.

To get it working you may write your own factory method or copy it from that CassandraHelper.

The simplest way is to setup it in Spring configuration:

```
<util:list id="contactPoints" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>127.0.0.1:9160</value>
</util:list>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess the examples are a bit less cookie-cutter than I thought they were.

I think if I can get the credentials field working it should boot now. Thank you for your help!